# GitLab refuses to merge branch

Tags: gitlab

Working with GitLab.

On GitLab the branch was created `11-feature1`. Some commits were done to it. Then a new branch was created `22-feature2`. The second branch was successfully merged into the `main` branch and work continue on the first `11-feature1`. Now I cannot merge that branch into main.

I am doing on the local:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase origin/main
### few conflicts stemmed from 22-feature2 is found and solved
$ git push
```

It looks good on the local side. But the remote (GitLab) still refuses to merge the branch `11-feature1` into the `main`. The message, "The source branch is 8 commits behind the target branch".

What to do?

I am now morally ready to completely abandon the branch `11-feature1` on GitLab and recreate it anew from the current `main` (which already has `22-feature2` in it). How to do it?

Comment: Normally i would do the following:
`git checkout 11-feature1;git pull;git checkout main;git pull;git checkout 11-feature1; # Need to be on the feature branch.git rebase main;# Fix merge conflict if anygit rebase --continue; # Repeat till all merge conflicts aren't resolved# Once resolved;git push -u origin 11-feature1 -f; #Force push;
`